# What kind of encoding is used by torrent files and how can i append trackers?

Tags: c++, c, bittorrent

I need to modify trackers in torrent files using C, What type of encoding do they use?? When I just print characters in ascii they print gibberish.
Or is there a direct way of adding trackers to a torrent file using C?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bencode

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried documenting yourself regarding .torrent file format ? The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torrent_file) seems to be pretty complete on this question.